# Is there a way to add a class to all elements that has a property set to true?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I have an object with a property of questions. questions is an array of 13 objects.Each object has a choices array that have between 2-4  objects and each object has an isCorrect property that is either true or null.

[image: questions array with property choices that's also an array with objects]

All my questions are being rendered. I have a button that I want to add a classname to each correct answer that the user selected. Do you guys have any suggestions of how I can achieve this?

```
{quiz.questions.map((question, index) => (
   <ContentWrapper key={question._key}>
     <h3>
      {`${index + 1}. `}
      {question.title}
     </h3>
     {question.choices.map(choice => (
       <ChoiceStyle id={"wrapper" + choice._key} key={choice._key}>
         <input
           type="radio"
           id={choice._key}
           name={question._key}
           onChange={updateScore}
           value={choice.isCorrect === null ? "0" : "1"}
            />
            <label htmlFor={choice._key}>{choice.title}</label>
          </ChoiceStyle>
        ))}

     <ButtonComponent
        type="button"
        buttonType="second"
        title="Sjekk svar"
        onClick={() => {
          calculateScore();
        }}
      />
```

That button just calculates the score but I might need to add another function to that button? I am also using styled components

Comment: can you share a piece of code showing how your component is structured?

Comment: @NnajiVictor yes, do you want me to update my question with my component?

Comment: Yes. That would work

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple approaches to do this, the easiest and less invasive way is to add a ternary condition to show/hide the class name based on an `isCorrect` property.

I'm assuming that `quiz` is a state that is changed in each `onChange` to refresh all the real-time changes on the quiz. At this point:

```
{quiz.questions.map((question, index) => (
   <ContentWrapper key={question._key}>
     <h3>
      {`${index + 1}. `}
      {question.title}
     </h3>
     {question.choices.map(choice => (
       <ChoiceStyle id={"wrapper" + choice._key} key={choice._key}>
         <input
           type="radio"
           id={choice._key}
           name={question._key}
           onChange={updateScore}
           className={`${choice.isCorrect ? 'is-valid':''}`}
           value={choice.isCorrect === null ? "0" : "1"}
            />
            <label htmlFor={choice._key}>{choice.title}</label>
          </ChoiceStyle>
        ))}

     <ButtonComponent
        type="button"
        buttonType="second"
        title="Sjekk svar"
        onClick={() => {
          calculateScore();
        }}
      />
```

The trick is the following ternary condition:

```
   className={`${choice.isCorrect ? 'is-valid':''}`}
```

> The problem that occurs is that the class gets applied right away. I
> don't want the correct answer to show up unless the user has clicked
> the button component

Then you will need to add a new property to your `choice` object to check and play with it. Let's assume something like:

```
     const choice={
        key: "some key"
        isCorrect: true
        /// other fields
      }


 // more code
{quiz.questions.map((question, index) => (
   <ContentWrapper key={question._key}>
     <h3>
      {`${index + 1}. `}
      {question.title}
     </h3>
     {question.choices.map(choice => (
       <ChoiceStyle id={"wrapper" + choice._key} key={choice._key}>
         <input
           type="radio"
           id={choice._key}
           name={question._key}
           onChange={updateScore}
           className={`${choice.isValid ? 'is-valid':'' }`}
           value={choice.isSelected === null ? "0" : "1"}
            />
            <label htmlFor={choice._key}>{choice.title}</label>
          </ChoiceStyle>
        ))}

     <ButtonComponent
        type="button"
        buttonType="second"
        title="Sjekk svar"
        onClick={() => {
          calculateScore();
        }}
      />
```

In each `updateScore`, you'll need to check if the choice is correct and matches your business logic and add the new property (`isValid`) to trigger it.

```
const updateScore =()=>{
   // some unknown logic

   // some validations and then:
   choice.isValid = true,
}
```

Since (I've assumed) that you are setting the `quiz` in React's state, the new property will force a refresh of the state, applying the class name in the user clicks.

Comment: The problem that occurs is that the class gets applied right away. I don't want the correct answer to show up unless the user has clicked the button component. And the class should not be applied if the user is wrong

Comment: Updated. Add a new property in your `updateScore` to check if the question matches the value and then, apply the new property accordingly. This will force the update of the React's state and it will display the new class